# OneSignal notification - update notification title on receive and before displaying it (android)

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

When the user receives notification I would like to change/update title or body. Before showing the notification to the user. My guess is to implement this inside `NotificationExtenderService.onNotificationProcessing` or `OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler`
But have no idea how the API documentation is not helping either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You can change reminder values inside onNotificationProcessing event.

```
protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
    OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
    overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
       @Override
       public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
           builder.setContentText....
           builder.setContentTitle...
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply override via builder methods setContentText().
Please, check the answer on issue in OneSignal repository.

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/717